# iOS 8.3 keyboard orientation bug

Tags: ios, keyboard, orientation

I am facing a strange iOS 8.3 issue which shows a keyboard on a wrong orientation like this (the view controller is in Landscape mode, but the keyboard show up in Portrait mode):

[image: the view controller is in Landscape mode, but the keyboard show up in Portrait mode]

I can trigger this issue by following these steps:

1. Create 2 `UIViewController` subClass: `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`
2. in `ViewControllerA` implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`
3. in `ViewControllerB` implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`
4. Create a `UINavigationController` subclass called `NavigationController`, implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and return `[self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]` (I'm doing this because I want to keep the NavigationController and it's rootVC from rotating)
5. Use the `NavigationController` as initial view controller of the app, set `ViewControllerA` as the `NavigationController`'s `rootViewContrller`
6. Launch the app, `ViewControllerA` will shown up in Portrait. Show a button on `ViewControllerA`, press the button will present `ViewControllerB` by using `presentViewController:animated:completion`
7. `ViewControllerB` will show up in Landscape; Show a text field on `ViewControllerB`, tap on the text field will trigger the keyboard, but the keyboard is in Portrait mode, just like the image above.

PS. You can download and run the Xcode project [on github](https://github.com/ultragtx/TestKeyboardBugOnIOS8_3)

This issue seems only appears on iOS 8.3. Am I doing something wrong ? Or maybe this is just another bug of iOS ?

By the way, this issue won't happen if you just show `ViewControllerA` directly without a `ViewController`. So if this is a bug of iOS, how can I avoid subclassing `UINavigationController` but still keep `ViewControllerA` which is the rootViewController of a `UINavigationController` from rotating.

---

UPDATE: This bug still appears on iOS 8.4, I fired a bug report and got replies from apple on June 17th 2015, they said it has been addressed in the latest iOS 9 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got around this issue by tricking the device into thinking that it was rotated into a different orientation and then into its intended orientation.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    if(!self.rotatingForDismissal)
    {
        [self.tableNumberTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }


    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.3"))
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(self.interfaceOrientation) forKey:@"orientation"];
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah ! This is a much better solution than mine. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I've asked a tech support and they said

> Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that this would be best handled as a bug report.

So seems that it's confirmed a system bug.

And my current solution is adding a ViewControllerC (support both portrait and landscape mode) between ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB: ViewControllerA should present ViewControllerC with animation, after ViewControllerC appeared, present ViewControllerB without animation.

To make the transition looks natural, you can set the same background colour as ViewControllerB to ViewControllerC, or take a screen shot of ViewControllerB and add it to ViewControllerC as a background image.

It's not a perfect solution, for users, they may find out ViewControllerB takes more time to load.

Comment: Did you file a radar against this issue ? Seeing the same issue from iOS 8.3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the keyboard appear correctly using the following.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"7.1") && SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0"))
  {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(orientation) forKey:@"orientation"];
  }
}
```

Note that using `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` does not cause side effects such as inappropriate auto rotation of views.